# use ssas date hierarchy in excel pivottable

Tags: excel, date, pivot, ssas, hierarchy

I have a Cube with a date hierarchy (year, quarter, month, day) and I also have set up attribute relationships for this hierarchy.

When I browse the cube with excel and make a pivottable, I can not use for example only the month attribute in the rows. When I drop the month in the rows, the entire date hierarchy shows up in the pivottable.

I don't want this, I just want the month showing up.

please help

Comment: Hi Abdel, Welcome to StackOveflow. Could you post code and the data if possible?

Comment: And also strange behaviour when using slicers with date hierarchy. Slicer for month for example, shows up with 'january, january, january, february, february, february, march, march, march,...It seems the slicer gives the same month for all the years available in the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a year and choose Show/Hide Fields. Then uncheck the Year level and any other levels you don't want to see.

The other choice is to have the developer of the cube leave the Month attribute hierarchy visible instead of hiding it after it was added to the hierarchy in the cube source code.

Comment: Your first option works, but is too much work. The second option is possible, but visual studio sais you should avoid making a dimension visible which is used in a hierarchy. I think this is because a hierarchy is made to make a cube faster, but when you leave the attributes visible, and the user uses these attributes, the cube is slower.

Comment: If the first option is too much work you can use my Excel add-in to hide all the levels you don't want in one pass: https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Choose%20Fields%20to%20Show&referringTitle=Home

Comment: @AbdelHiha hiding the attribute hierarchy is just a best practice but if you want to see a flat list of months then leave that attribute visible. If we were talking about a hierarchy of a million customers I would be more worried about the performance impact.

Comment: @AbdelHiha if I have answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.