# MDX - Only return chosen hierarchy level

Tags: mdx

I have an MDX Query in which I ask to get the 3rd level within a given hierarchy. When I am querying in MS SQL Server Managemnt Studio, I only get the selected hierarchy. However, when I run the query in an Excel table, I get all three levels.

What I ask for:

- 1st level

  - 2nd level

    - 3rd level <--- I only ask to recieve this guy.

What I get in Excel table:

- 1st level <--- returned

  - 2nd level <--- returned

    - 3rd level <--- returned

What I get in SQL Management studio table:

- 1st level

  - 2nd level

    - 3rd level <--- returned

So my question is:

1) Can I specify exactly what level I want to retrieve in the Excel table?

2) Can I retrieve all three levels in MS SQL Server Management Studio if I wanted to?

Overall I am interested in being able to control what is retrieved, of course :)

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1):

See here for how to hide level 1-2 in Excel:
[use ssas date hierarchy in excel pivottable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074463/use-ssas-date-hierarchy-in-excel-pivottable/34079553#34079553)

How are you running your query in SSMS. Cube browser? MDX query? If you wrote the query then what query did you try?

Comment: In SSMS it is an MDX query. What I am trying to query in MDX for instance is SELECT [Measures].[Real Earnings] ON 0,
[ProductHierarchies].[ProductHierarchyLevel3].[ProductHierarchyLevel3] ON 1
FROM [FinancialDM]. When I put the query into an Excel table (not Pivot] I retrieve both level 1 and 2.

Comment: The MDX query window will put all levels into one column. ProductHierarchyLevel3 makes me think that is just the third level. If you said "[ProductHierarchies].[ProductHierarchy].Members ON 1" all levels would show in one column. But if you said "[ProductHierarchies].[ProductHierarchyLevel2].[ProductHierarchyLevel2] * "[ProductHierarchies].[ProductHierarchyLevel3].[ProductHierarchyLevel3] ON 1" you will get two columns. Let me know if subtotals are important.

Comment: Have similar issue.
SSMS returns exactly what you want, but in Excel you get all upper levels.